# ng-repeat through two different arrays

Tags: angularjs

I want to do something that looks like this  :

```
<tbody>
      <tr  ng-repeat="item1 in list1 "  ng-repeat="item2 in list2" >
        <td>{{item2.a}}</td>
        <td>  {{item1.b}}</td>
        <td> {{item2.c }}</td>
        <h3> <td> {{item1.d}}</td></h3>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
```

note : the two list are completely different and there is no way of regrouping them (which'll make the whole thing a lot easier) or at least that's not what I want to do

Comment: you want to iterate through both lists at once? do they have the same length?

Comment: merge both lists using [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) in the controller itself before displaying it into UI.

you can use _.extend function. maybe this is what you need -
https://lostechies.com/chrismissal/2012/10/05/extending-objects-in-underscore/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to combine the 2 arrays it is assumed they are the same length in which case you can loop over one of the arrays and use `$index` to reference it's counterpart

```
<tr ng-repeat="item1 in list1 ">
    <td>{{list2[$index].a}}</td>
    <td>{{item1.b}}</td>
    <td>{{list2[$index].c }}</td>
    <td><h3> {{item1.d}}</h3></td>    
</tr>
```